# Getting duplicate results in many to many query

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, count, many-to-many

I have designed a bookstore app with these tables. There's a `book` with an M2M relation to `author`. Lastly, there's table `reader` which keeps track of which user has read the book i.e. an entry in the `read` table means that book has been read by the corresponding user.

**Relation defined in** [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1fc15/3)

I want to select the books with their author names and also keep a count of how many people have read a particular book. Here's my query :

**Question** : Count of the number of readers for a book is wrong (coincidentally equal to the number of authors). For a book with more than 1 reader, the author names are repeated.

```
  SELECT b.id, b.title, COUNT(r.user1_id) AS read_ct, 
         array_agg(author.name)
  FROM book b
  LEFT OUTER JOIN reader r ON r.book_id = b.id      
  LEFT OUTER JOIN book_author ba ON ba.book_id = b.id    
  LEFT OUTER JOIN author ON author.id = ba.author_id          
  GROUP BY b.id
```

Which of these solutions is better ?

**Solution 1** : Use `DISTINCT clause i.e.

```
 SELECT b.id, b.title, COUNT(DISTINCT r.user1_id) AS read_ct, 
     array_agg(DISTINCT author.name)
```

**Solution 2** : Use subquery

```
 SELECT s.id, s.title, s.names, COUNT(r.used1_id) AS read_ct
 FROM (
   SELECT b.id, b.title, array_agg(author.name) AS names
   FROM book b
   LEFT OUTER JOIN book_author ba ON ba.book_id = b.id    
   LEFT OUTER JOIN author ON author.id = ba.author_id          
   GROUP BY b.id
 ) AS s
 LEFT OUTER JOIN reader r ON r.book_id = s.id
 GROUP BY s.id, s.title, s.names
```

Comment: @dezso 2) If I don't use `DISTINCT`, how can I fix the problem of duplicate results for both `author_names` and `COUNT` 3) I've removed `r.book_id`, that was redundant.

Comment: You can remove the joins one by one, checking which one is the culprit for the duplication.

Comment: @dezso I've added a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1fc15/3) with the bare minimum `JOIN` to get my results. The moment I combine `COUNT` with `array_agg`, this problem crops up i.e. its doing a cartesian product like output.

Comment: Just for the record, I thought about the other `DISTINCT` in my now-deleted comment.

Answer (score 1):

Objective: Count book's readers. 
Display book title, count, authors.

- JOIN the (Subquery: book.array_agg(authors))
- TO (Subquery: count book readers)
- TO Book for id, title.

I think the logical error, as you mentioned Cartesian product, was aggregating two different aggregations at the same time...

Something like this should work:

PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT id, title, read_ct.Readers, Authors.Names
FROM book b
JOIN ( SELECT book_id, array_agg( name) as Names
       FROM book_author ba
       JOIN author a
       ON a.id = ba.author_id
       GROUP by book_id
      ) Authors
ON Authors.book_id = b.id
JOIN (
    SELECT book_id, count(r.user1_id) Readers
    FROM reader r
    GROUP BY book_id ) read_ct
on read_ct.book_id = b.id
```

SQL Server:

```
SELECT id, title, read_ct.Readers, STUFF(
                (SELECT ', ', a.name
                FROM book_author ba
                    JOIN author a
                    ON a.id = ba.author_id
                WHERE ba.book_id = b.id
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
                .value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')
    FROM book b
    JOIN (
        SELECT book_id, count(r.user1_id) Readers
        FROM reader r
        GROUP BY book_id ) read_ct
    on read_ct.book_id = b.id
```

Comment: shot for clearing that up. Also, the edits to my answer are greatly appreciated.